# how to reverse a sequence of digits enter by user ion python without using string and use function?

Tags: python

how to reverse a sequence of digits entered by the user without using a string and the code is in the function?

the output will be something like this:

The reverse of the digits `123456 is 654321` 
`123456` is input from user

Comment: You can use a stack as data structure. You can find some more informations on how to do that [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-in-python/)

Comment: What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

try `%` modulo and `//` integer division

```py
d = 123456

num = 0
while(d):
    t = d%10
    num = num*10 + t
    d = d //10
    
print(num) #654321
```

Comment: why need to add 10?